# How to get iMessage scroll view sticky snap with animation?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, autolayout

I've been at this question for a while, and I don't see any good solutions for how to create a smooth animation for when scrolling up and down. I can use the scroll view delegates to determine scrolling up or down, but I don't understand how to achieve the smooth animation of the MESSAGES and SEARCH BAR to hide while the Tableview expands. I tried using Stack Views to make the UITextfield and UILabel hide when scrolling up and show when scrolling down, and be aligned to the tableview. This created a jerky motion of the tableview snapping up as the constraints got updated.

```
 func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        // moved to top
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.2, options: .curveEaseOut,
                       animations: {self.headerView.alpha = 1.0},
                       completion: { _ in  self.headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.frostedGlass
```

Are there any libraries or can someone point me in the right direction of how to achieve the desired effect of a smooth transition for the top view and labels when scrolling up and down?

[image: Scrolled Up]

[image: Scrolled down and hide search bar and Messages label]

Comment: Sorry, but what are you trying to do?

Comment: Create a spring effect bounce like the iMessage app. Maybe I should upload a GIF showing the behavior.